# PlaywrightException: Connection closed (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: System error - only when debugging

Tags: c#, .net, playwright, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have some UI test written in MS Test 2 framework.

The test runs fine when I run it from Visual Studio 2022's test explorer.

When I try to debug the test I'm getting:

```
Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException: Connection closed (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: System error.
   at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.WriteToNonSeekableAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.WriteToNonSeekableAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.StdIOTransport.SendAsync(String message))

  Stack Trace: 
Connection.SendMessageToServerAsync[T](String guid, String method, Object args)
Frame.WaitForFunctionAsync(String expression, Object arg, FrameWaitForFunctionOptions options)
MyTest.MyAsyncMethod() line 23
ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
```

on following call to WaitForFunctionAsync:

```cs
  var jshandle = await Page.WaitForFunctionAsync(script,
                null, 
                new() { Timeout = 5000, PollingInterval = 300 });
```

**The error occurs only if the breakpoint is hit before the call.**

I'm experiencing similar behavior with QuerySelectorAsync().

How can I debug playwright tests?!

Comment: Lookt like a racing condition somewhere (between code and page lifecycle) I think. I can't make this out by the code part in the OP but maybe page lifecycle already ended?

Comment: @Firewizz: Are you able to debug and step trough any Playwright .NET code in MS Test tests?

Comment: No, and didnt try. Never worked with playwright, just judged on error and your story. Maybe a tip to look there since nobody has responded yet. Maybe that it could help ;)

Comment: Maybe this is of help: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-dotnet/issues/1728

Comment: In mu case tests runs fine if no breakpoint is hit. But I was able to debug new playwright testproject, so at least I know the problem is on my side

Comment: I got same issue, running 'normal' tests using NUnit with Visual Studio 2022 (v17.0.4)
Only fails when a breakpoints is hit before an async call

Comment: Have you checked the part for default timeout? It seems like the session is closed as while the breakpoint is initiated and the session is a timeout and in normal run it is working. Try checking internal action timeout and global timeout